# Windows got stuck on lock screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update

This has been a sudden issue that I have been facing for a while. What happened was I tried to install some Vmware player latest version but each time I tried to ran I got windows info saying cant run Vmware on Windows even though it was the latest version. It used to run fine even with the older version 5.6 was running fine but after a certain windows update most of the things arent working well now. This was one of the issue.

In order to resolve this I tried to uninstall one of the installed windows update (update for windows KB...) but seems like everything has gone wrong. At the boot itself the windows get stuck on lock screen showing only time without showing any cursor or pin bar. I tried to restart the system by pressing power button several times but same thing windows got stuck.

Any help please. [image][image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VMWare Workstation not opening anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/1496099/vmware-workstation-not-opening-anymore/1496211#1496211).  Due to the delay in the error message being provided as a screenshot, I failed to identify this as a duplicate until now, upgrading VMWare Player to a supported version is a legitimate solution to this problem.

Comment: That doesnt solve this problem as that was an upgraded version you said yes, its the issue with compatibility as the windows giving message clears that not supporting per updated windows. But still I got the same error message on upgradition as well. You just cant rely on updated version of VMware as windows updates constantly. Hence, you need to prevent some updates as in the below answer Ive mentioned to make it work.

Comment: I know for a fact the current version of `VMWare Player Pro` supports Windows 10 version 1903.  Preventing a cumulative update will only help for so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the VMWARE error by uninstalling the "Update for Windows (KB..)"
and disabling dependent updates on restart via microsoft hide update troubleshooter and on restart was able to work with VMWARE.

[image]