# VMWare Workstation not opening anymore

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

After some Windows 10 upgrades (I don't know exactly which ones), my VMWare Workstation 15.0.4 just doesn't open anymore.
I click on it and nothing happens, not even an error message ...
I researched some articles but found nothing conclusive.
Repaired VMware, uninstalled, upgraded version, but nothing changed.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtual Machine is not running in windows 10 Home](https://superuser.com/questions/1480801/virtual-machine-is-not-running-in-windows-10-home)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After some Windows 10 upgrades (I don't know exactly which ones), my VMWare Workstation 15.0.4 just doesn't open anymore.

VMWare Workstation 15.1 and earlier is not compatible with Windows 10 version 1903.  You will need to upgrade to VMWare Workstation 15.5 to resolve your problem.

> Does anyone have any ideas?

You must have not installed VMWare Workstation 15.5 when you attempted to reinstall or upgrade WMWare Workstation.

Comment: This answer is entirely based on my personal experience with VMWare Workstation 15.1, which was installed, and was specifically called out as being incompatible and was blocking 1903 from being installed on a machine running Windows 10 version 1809 a few weeks ago